# Change e-mail subject

Tags: php, forms, email

I am using the following php script to handle my form. I'm not really good at PHP, now I want to change the $email_subject = "Contact via website" to "Contact via website and the name the user as entered in the form. Is this possible.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "info@lowie-design.be";
    $email_subject = "Contact via website";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "Onze verontschuldigen maar er is een fout gebeurd met het formulier dat u heeft ingevuld. ";

        echo "Volgende fouten hebben zich voorgedaan:<br/><br/>";
        echo $error."<br/><br/>";
        echo "Probeer alsjeblieft opnieuw.<br/><br/>";
        die();
    }

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['naam']) || !isset($_POST['email']) ||        !isset($_POST['interesse']) || !isset($_POST['tijd']) || !isset($_POST['details'])) {
    died('Het spijt ons, maar er blijkt een probleem zich voor te doen met het formulier dat je hebt ingevuld.');
}

$names = $_POST['naam']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$intrests = $_POST['interesse']; // not required
$time = $_POST['tijd']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['details']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'U heeft een ongeldig e-mail adres ingegeven.<br />';
}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$names)) {
    $error_message .= 'U heeft een ongeldige naam ingegeven.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'U heeft ongeldige commentaar ingegeven.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Formulier details volgen:\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Naam: ".clean_string($names)."\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Interesse in: ".clean_string($intrests)."\n";
$email_message .= "Tijdsbestek: ".clean_string($time)."\n";
$email_message .= "Details: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

Comment: **Not an answer, just a couple of things I saw wrong with your script** after the if statement where you check if post doesnt exist, you would need to put an `else` statement around the part where you put the POST values in variables. Also you say that `$_POST['intrests']` is not required, same with `$_POST['tijd']` yet you use them in the validation if statement. So if one of them is not set, it will die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
$email_subject = "Contact via website from " . $_POST['naam'];
```

Comment: Array to string conversion is not possible. Gives `[array]`

Comment: Why should `$_POST['naam']` be an array? He is using `preg_match($string_exp,$names)` anyways?